# Semisimple elements in compact Lie groups

Tags: lie-algebras

Suppose that $\mathfrak{g}$ is a Lie algebra. We call $\mathfrak{g}$ a **compact Lie algebra** if there exists an inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ on $\mathfrak{g}$ such that $$\langle[Z,X],Y\rangle+\langle X,[Z,Y]\rangle=0,\forall X,Y,Z\in\mathfrak{g}.$$On the other hand, an element $X\in\mathfrak{g}$ is called **semisimple** if $ad(X)$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$, where $ad$ is the adjoint representation.

I want to show that each element in a compact Lie algebra is semisimple.

Comment: So it seems like you should show $\operatorname{ad}(X)$ is diagonalizable. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: OK, I can solve this problem by your hint. Thanks